# How to make Lightning datatable records in the right column?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

JS :

```
@track columns = [
        {
            type: 'action',
            typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions},cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'cssClass'} },
        },
        {label: 'N° Conv', fieldName: 'ConventionNb__c',type: this.test ,sortable: true,cellAttributes: {
            class: { fieldName: 'convSigne'},
           
        }},
        { 
            label: 'Nom du conventions',value :  'Name',fieldName: 'Name',type: 'Picklist',sortable: true,cellAttributes: {
                class: { fieldName: 'convSigne' },
            }}
    ]


@wire(getConventions)
wiredGetConventions0(result){
    const { data, error } = result;
    console.log('Methode Cases*****', result);
    if(data) {
        
        this.conventions = result.data.map((record) => {
            this.convSigne = record.ConventionEnvoyee__c === true && record.ConventionRetournee__c === true ? 'slds-text-color_error': 'defaultText';
            let cssClass  = record.ConventionEnvoyee__c === true && record.ConventionRetournee__c === true ? 'slds-show': 'slds-hide';
                return {...record,
                    'convSigne': this.convSigne,
                    'cssClass':cssClass}
            
            
        });
```

HTML

```
 <lightning-datatable data={conventions} columns={columns} key-field="Id" sorted-by={sortedBy} 
            sorted-direction={sortedDirection} 
            onsort={onSort} onrowaction={handleRowActions} hide-checkbox-column="true" >
```

[image]

I believe that this is due to **OnrowAction** which is **hidden** because it doesn't met the *condition* but i can't find how to fix the records with the columns for this *condition* ..

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What are you trying to do? What isn't working? Please edit your question so we can understand what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

By using `slds-hide`, you're shifting everything left a column, because the cells are literally not shown. Instead, you'll want to disable the menu items if the condition is met.

Something like this can be used:

```
const dynamicActions = (row, done)  => {
  done(
    [
      {
        name: 'remove', 
        label: 'Remove', 
        disabled: row.disabled
      }
    ]
  );
}
```

Which you then just specify for the rowActions:

```
 columns = [
  { 
    type: 'action', 
    fixedWidth: 30,
    typeAttributes: { 
      rowActions: dynamicActions
    } 
  },
  { 
    label:'Name', 
    fieldName: 'Name' 
  },
 ];
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/KWtKDVjegNWfPF1fItL8/src/app.js?p=stories).

You can also selectively disable the menu items, if you prefer. If you have only one action, consider using a button instead of an action column; this way you could just use the disabled attribute instead.